# CMake Warning, cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target

Tags: python, linux, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, conda

I am trying to build [Pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/tree/v0.5) v0.5 by my own. However when executing cmake I get the following warning for several builds:

here for example with VideoViewer

```
Cmake Warning at tools/VideoViewer/CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_executable):
 Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target VideoViewer becaause 
 files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit 
 directorys:


runtime library[libpython2.7.so.1.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be 
hidden by files in: /opt/conda/lib
```

However, the compiliation works, and after this I do `make install`
This results in a later error when I try to build another project that relies on Pangolin. There he cannot find certain classes etc., which resuls in a build error.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 on a Docker Image, I have Anaconda installed for Python.

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` looks like the following:

```
/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64/:opt/conda/lib
```

Removing the `/opt/conda/lib` part from the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did not help.

Comment: Is the Python from conda also on your `PATH`? If so, can you remove it from there and try again?

Comment: Do you mean /opt/conda/lib ? Yes, I already tried that - it is mentioned above, or do you mean sth else?